# How to increase downloading speed in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: networking

Can anyone help me out by suggesting any good software or any other way to increase downloading speed for files downloaded through firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XDM Download Manager](https://github.com/subhra74/xdm#downloads) for Ubuntu. It downloads 5-6 times faster than conventional downloaders. It's opensource and free. It also has [firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xdm-browser-monitor/) and [Chrome extension](https://subhra74.github.io/xdm/redirect.html?target=chrome), which grabs dowload links from popular websites.